# Differentiate using product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Differentiate $$R(t) = (4t + e^t)(4 - \sqrt t) $$
> $$R'(t) = $$

When I used the product rule $$ f'(x) *g(x) + f(x)*g'(x) $$

I get $$(16 -4 \sqrt t + 4e^t - e^t\sqrt t) + (-(4t - e^t / ( 2\sqrt t )))$$

What do I do from here? When I input this as the answer is says incorrect. I've been stuck on this for hours, any help is appreciated.

edit:
here is a screenshot

[image: The Problem]

edit 2:
everyone was correct and apparently I just cant type
I had already found this answer hours ago, but apparently im stupid and type it incorrectly into the box and wasted hours I could have been doing something else. I feel so dumb

Comment: Does the system have a requirement that denominators be rationalized?

Comment: @Starlight I have no idea. Maybe? Would I just have to rewrite it as -(4t sqrt(1) - e^t sqrt(t)/ (2t)) I am canadian

Comment: The term $-e^t\cdot t$ should be $-e^t\cdot \sqrt{t}$

Comment: How is being Canadian relevant here?

Comment: No need to feel dumb -- but put it to the lessons learned :)

Comment: If you are going to type into the system shown, you should learn some LaTeX. It's bad design to expect math students to learn Latex. But there are hidden expectations (unfortuanately). You just encountered one.....

Comment: @Starlight WebWork supports TeX-like input, but there is a toolbar that appears on the right that provides templates for common objects such as exponents and square roots. This is similar in MyMathLab and WebAssign.

Comment: So then it's better to use the toolbar.....less chances of a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we need to find the corresponding $f’$ and $g’$.

Here,

$$f’ = 4 + e^t$$
$$g’ = -\frac{1}{2}t^{\frac{-1}{2}} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{t}}$$

Now when we plug that into the product rule formula we get

$$f’(t)g(t) + f(t)g’(t) = (4 + e^t)(4-\sqrt{t}) + (4t + e^t)(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}})$$

Which we can expand by foiling as

$$(16-4\sqrt{t}+4e^t -e^t\sqrt{t})+ (-4t\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} - e^t\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}) $$

We could further simplify it to

$$ (16-4\sqrt{t}+4e^t -e^t\sqrt{t})+ (-\frac{4t}{2\sqrt{t}} - \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{t}}) $$

Some things cancel here:

$$ (16-4\sqrt{t}+4e^t -e^t\sqrt{t})+ (-\frac{2t}{\sqrt{t}} - \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{t}}) $$

If you wanted you could take the common denominator and subtract numerators:

$$ (16-4\sqrt{t}+4e^t -e^t\sqrt{t})+ (-\frac{4t-e^t}{2\sqrt{t}})$$

Then we can remove the brackets and replace $+(-a)$ with $-a$:

$$ 16-4\sqrt{t}+4e^t -e^t\sqrt{t}-\frac{4t-e^t}{2\sqrt{t}}$$

Maybe you could simplify more but this seems enough reduced enough to me.

What I got above is actually the same exact thing you got. Hence, there doesn’t seem to be a mistake

**Edit 1**: In general any form simplified or not should work, I mean simplifying doesn’t change the expression it just reduces it.

**Edit 2**: Oh it was correct… Ok

Answer (score 2):

From your recent edit I see you're using WebWork (my university uses it too).

I'm going to present an alternate solution that still uses the product rule, but we can expand the multiplication first, thereby possibly eliminating any small mistakes.

By doing the multiplications, we have $$R(t) = 16t + 4e^t - 4t\sqrt{t} - e^t \sqrt{t}.$$ We can recall that $\sqrt{t} = t^\frac{1}{2}$ and by using some exponent rules, we can further write $$R(t) = 16t + 4e^t - 4t^\frac{3}{2} - e^t \sqrt{t}$$ which results in a combination of three easy functions to differentiate, and only the last term requires some work.

Let's do the side calculation of differentiating the last term. Indeed, by the product rule,

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( e^t \sqrt{t} \right) &= e^t \frac{d}{dt} \left( \sqrt{t} \right) + \sqrt{t} \frac{d}{dt} \left( e^t \right) \\
&= \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{t}} + e^t \sqrt{t} \\
\end{align*}
and now by using the power rule (and the fact that $e^t$ is its own derivative),

$$R'(t) = 16 + 4e^t -6\sqrt{t} - \left( \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{t}} + e^t \sqrt{t} \right) $$

which can be tidied up a bit by passing the minus sign through (i.e., distributing):

$$\boxed{R'(t) = 16 + 4e^t -6\sqrt{t} - \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{t}} - e^t \sqrt{t}} $$

Answer (score -3):

*"What do I do from here?"* If you worked on it **for hrs** u simply use the wrong tools. "My" CAS returns $\displaystyle -\sqrt{t}e^t+4e^t-4\sqrt{t}+\mathrm{16} + \frac{-e^t-4t}{2\sqrt{t}}$

Again step by step:
I defined `f:=4*t+exp(t);`
Next I defined `g:=4-sqrt(t);`
Then I did `df(f, t)*g;` what resulted in $-\sqrt{t}e^t+4e^t-4\sqrt{t}+\mathrm{16}$
Then I did `df(g, t)*f;` what resulted in $\displaystyle \frac{-e^t-4t}{2\sqrt{t}}$
The last step I did w/o CAS and got the a. m. result. IMO this is detailed enough now for almost all students.

Comment: I don't think this is helpful. Anybody can check with a CAS, but the learning experience is to be careful with the manipulations - common thing I see with my students.

Comment: What is CAS? I did get that answer but I formatted the question wrong because I'm tired. What do I do after? Because this doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: @BorisSchmoris -- the last step was to add the two partial results, $f'*g$ and $f*g'$, to get the final result as shown above.